# Purpose of curly braces in Statistics? (Programming in R)

Tags: statistics

I'm fairly new to Statistics and have just started Programming in `R`.

I'm trying to write the following expression in `R` ready to store in an object but i'm unsure of the purpose of the curly braces in the expression.

[image]

According to [this source](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/UseBracketsAndBracesCorrectly.html), the braces serve a different purpose to parenthesis.

I'm testing my `R` code on [Wolfram-Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-%281/th%29%29*%28log%281%2b%28%28e%5E%28-th*x%29-1%29*%28%28e%5E%28-th*y%29%29-1%29%29/%28%28e%5E-th%29-1%29%29%29;), (click to see) which outputs the following:

[image]

This is my code:

```
  (-(1/th))*(log(1+((e^(-th*x)-1)*((e^(-th*y))-1))/((e^-th)-1)));
```

However my main query is that this may be incorrect as `R` doesn't recognise curly braces: `{ }`. I substituted them for parenthesis.

What is the correct representation of the above expression **in R** and do the braces serve a purpose?

It should be noted that `e`,`x` and`y` are variables and `th` is the value of theta. 
It should also be noted that I was sent here from the programming exchange...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The curly braces are the same as parentheses -- typically they are used to enclose an expression that already uses parentheses. Your "source" is specific to Mathematica syntax, not mathematics as a whole. Just use parentheses in R and you should be OK.